# Is there a way to run bitcoind without being a full node?

Tags: bitcoind

I want to be able to run bitcoind on a VPS I rented, but I neither have good bandwidth nor RAM so I do not want to be a full node.  How would I go about configuring things so that I can run bitcoind without acting as a full node or relaying transactions?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: As David said, what are you trying to do? If you simply wanted to be able to receive bitcoins, we could give an answer. If you wanted to be able to talk to the P2P network of Bitcoin, we could answer that. But you haven't stated your full intent for avoiding a full node. Maybe you want a [wallet that isn't a full node?](https://electrum.org/)

Answer (score 5):

You might not want to run `bitcoind` at all then, you could just use a `client-only node` (AKA `thin client`) tool such as [bitcoinj](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/).

Before going for a `thin client` approach, make sure you understand the [differences from running a full node and also some security concerns](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Thin_Client_Security).

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoind does not support running in anything but a "full" mode.

Answer (score 2):

As of bitcoin core v0.11, there is a way to run bitcoind in prune mode:
[How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/how-can-i-run-bitcoind-in-pruning-mode)

Comment: Which is neither relevant for ram or bandwidth. More appropriate would have been a pointer about blocks-only mode. ;) but really the question is answered and most likely a XY-problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some commands like connect for direct control of its peering. Trying to run the daemon without its database may be difficult, it looks for the database on startup. It might be easier if the daemon and its blockchain could be run in different locations, I havent heard of this yet.