# Bitcoind functionality w/o running a full node

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I'd like to do some of the example in "Mastering Bitcoin, Programming the Open Blockchain" using bitoind on my Ubuntu system. Is there a program (possibly bitcoind itself) that allows me to do this w/o setting up a full not which I can currently not do for Hardware reasons?

I would mainly like to be able to explore transaction with comments such as `bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction` for instance.

Many thanks and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: I guess you could try and use an Api?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use some API that provides the same functionality.

See https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/decoderawtransaction

> bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction

And much more calls/commands are listed there.

Does this fit your needs?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty good from what I have seen in that short period of time. Let me ask you as well, out of curiosity, is there something like this for the command line in Linux (Ubuntu)?

Comment: You mean something like the bitcoin core RPC client? https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list, see this answer -> https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24563/is-there-a-way-to-run-bitcoind-without-being-a-full-node

Comment: Ok, i.e. something like bitcoinj is a tool I might want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run bitcoind in regtest mode, which would allow you to experiment with the RPC and everything without having to download the main blockchain (regtest will create its own private blockchain for you to use, which you can mine on using the `generate` RPC command).